# how to runtime list of functions in a .h

Tags: c++

I have a large .h file where many functions are defined. These functions are what the user calls at runtime to execute specific operations with my code. It's kind of tedious to remember the names of these functions and often even I have to go back to the source code to remember the exact name that I gave to these functions.

So, I was wondering that I can write a function that lists all the functions defined in a given .h file, maybe even filtering according to some regular expression.
The "search" must be doable at runtime without reading the source, if possible.

Comment: grep funcname header.h

Comment: I'm uncertain where/which language this function should be written in.  As koodawg noted in his comments, it's perfectly possible to generate the list *outside* of the program, and then reference it later; perhaps from within the program, perhaps as a standalone text file.

Comment: You can do it in C#, but you can't do it in C++ without writing code outside of C++ that parses the header file and then links the results.

Answer (score 2):

You could hard code such a function by hand, or write a script that analyses the .h file to generate the code.

As far as I know there's no way of doing this directly in c++ as it would require the use of [reflections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29) and c/c++ is not a reflective language.

**Update:**

It might be possible to access the library's symbol table to perform the desired task if you are operating on a linux system. Look at the man page for [dladdr](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dladdr) for further reading (there's also an example to play around with a little bit).

My approach would be trying to narrow the address-space for your library and afterwards scan for symbols via `dladdr(void* addr, Dl_info* info)`

The command [nm](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nm) might help you on the way, as it list available symbols and their addresses for object files

Comment: Thanks to every body for replying. I see that is a bit outside the scope of C++ itself. I may better develop a function that analyzes the .h (in perl, bash script or whatever) and writes down a "support file" that the user can refer to at runtime, without looking into the source, or I may even write a function in the code that analyzes this support file in search of the possible name that the user may be looking for.

Answer (score 2):

There are tools like doxygen  (just google it) that will help you document source code; but it is not runtime.

But the problem seems deeper that it looks.

You need to write meaningful function and method names; names that will mean something to the people writing the code.

You need to write valid and descriptive (and at least minimal) comments for functions that will describe the functions (that can be more complex than the name might suggest).

Split code into logical namespace/classes (and files) to clear up the code and limit the number of functions per header files.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

The only way i know of is to fstream the .h file and parse it. Or you can go the dummy way and just save the function names in a vector or array or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the best way of doing something like this, where you want meta data from your header files accessible from within the program, is to create a database of all the functions you want (in some external file) and then run a script to *generate* the header file.

For example, you could have a CSV or TSV text file that has

```
  FunctionName,Description,Arg0Type, Arg0Description,...
```

Then write another program (in python/perl/C++/etc) to create a header file that looks like

```
 int FunctionName(Arg0Type arg0);
  ....
```

and a c file out of

```
 struct {
    int (*funcptr)();
    const char* name;
    const char* description;
 } database[] = { 
     { FunctionName, "FunctionName", "Description"},
      ...
 };
```

and then write code in your application to search the `database[]` for help and function pointers.